# Generating build from the terminal is failing, but it's working from the "Run App" option(When clicking the "Run App")

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, terminal

When I'm trying to build the project from the terminal it's keep failing.

```
kaptDebugKotlin failed
```

I suspect that something wrong with Java JDK path. But I set the java_home in both bash file and Android studio.

**I set the JDK1.8 home as java_home and JDK location in Android Studio.**

NB: I'm using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.java.home=<JDK location>
```

Also check exact problem with these commands:

```
--stacktrace --info --scan
```